# Getting authentication Error when using "Send a HTTP Request to DevOps" from LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am Trying to automate the approval of Pull request from logic app using "Send a HTTP Request to DevOps" action. Getting below authentication error.

Tried below options but nothing worked.

1. Created new PAT with Full Access and passed to header.
2. Enabled "Third-party application access via OAuth" in org policies
3. Tried Basic, Bearer authentication

[image]

`Error: { "status": 401, "message": "TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: abcd1234-ac34-ac34-abcd1234\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server\",\"typeKey\":\"UnauthorizedRequestException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3000}\r\nclientRequestId: abcd1234-ac34-ac34-abcd1234", "error": { "message": "TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: abcd1234-ac34-ac34-abcd1234\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server\",\"typeKey\":\"UnauthorizedRequestException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3000}" }, "source": "vsts-eus.azconn-eus-003.p.azurewebsites.net" }`

Comment: Did you encode the PAT in base64 first with no username when trying Basic auth?

Comment: After encoding the PAT to base64, the flow worked as intended. Please change the comment to answer so that i can accept the answer. Thanks @Skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you encode the PAT to base64 with no username when using basic auth in Azure DevOps.

Comment: I used a base64 encoder tool for the PAT but I'm still getting the same error. What am I missing? I'm using the GET wiki api endpoint.

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat

Comment: Unfortunately not. I got the base64 encode of `:<my PAT>`. I'm still getting the same 401 error that the OP is getting.